# how to remove session variables/stotage in html page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am setting and getting session variables in my html pages loke below

```
   sessionStorage.setItem('AbnormalLogout', AbnormalLogout);
    var AbnormalLogout= sessionStorage.getItem("AbnormalLogout");
```

but when i use

```
 sessionStorage.removeItem('AbnormalLogout');
```

i can get this session variable using getitem property on another page after redirecting

Answer (score 0):

Try:

this will completely clear localStorage

```
localStorage.clear();
```

this will completely clear sessionStorage

```
sessionStorage.clear();
```

Try this also:

```
Object.keys(sessionStorage).forEach(function(item) {
    sessionStorage.removeItem(item);
  });
```

Comment: Where r u setting the value into the sessionStorage, 
if it is in the master layout page, it will be executed on each page load.